# MFC Application icon in the taskbar

Tags: c++, mfc, icons

In a MFC windows application, the right icon is shown in the taskbar if I run the .exe file created through a release/debug build. However it doesn't show and only loads windows default icon if the application gets installed on the machine.

What is the reason behind this latter behaviour?

Comment: Is your application icon the first one in the app's resource file?

Comment: Create a brand new application with the wizard that doesn't do anything. Then copy everything from it that has to do with the icon.

Comment: Logicrat, Good point. Though it is the first item in the .rc file with the lowest id

Comment: Mark: I took your suggestion. The problem lies in the application desktop shortcut icon not being set in the setup project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your icon resources aren't available in all sizes? I.e. the 16 px is used for the task bar, but there is a default one for the bigger size that is used for the shortcut.